# Нужна ли запятая после "красоты"?

Tags: пунктуация

"Помимо природной красоты особой популярностью здесь пользуется банджи-джампинг".

Answer (score 2):

Обороты с предлогом ПОМИМО обособляются очень часто. И в этом случае запятая тоже, я думаю, нужна.  Оборот имеет значение включения/исключения, стоит в начале предложения, выделяется интонационно.

Обороты со значением включения, исключения и замещения ... ***выделяются или не выделяются запятыми по условиям контекста: в зависимости от степени их распространения, места расположения в предложении.***
Такие обороты включают предлоги и предложные сочетания: *кроме, наряду, помимо, включая, исключая, за исключением, сверх, вместо и др.*
[Здесь](http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/271-obosoblennyedopolneniya.html)